# Graphql query with http.get fails

Tags: angularjs, http, graphql

I am trying to pass a simple `graphql` query to my `http.get`. There are 2 issues here: The id does not take the empID and the request fails badly. Please advise

Here's the code:

```
EmployeeService.prototype.getEmployee = function(empID) {
 let deferred = ij.q.defer();

  // Get the endpoint.
  const myQuery = `{
    employee(id: {empID}) {
      id
      items {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }`;
  const gql = 'graphql';
  const queryURL = `${gql}?query=${encodeURI(myQuery)}`;

  $http.get(queryURL).then((response) => {
    let result = response && response.data;
    if (result) {
      deferred.resolve(result);
    } 
  }, (reason) => {
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: It looks like your empID variable is being passed along naked, try putting it into quotations. GraphQL expects everything in quotes, you can't specify plain integers.

Comment: Making the `empID` in quotes doesn't solve the problem.